# How to create and maintain multiples of the same object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, object, bounce

I'm trying to get multiple Ball objects to form on screen and bounce around.  I have it working fine for one, but I am having problems adding more.  Ideally, the amount of balls will vary, but for now I am trying to just get two into an array to change the rest of the code.

My problem is that everything compiles and runs fine, but I still only have one ball.  This is where I suspect the problem arises.

I also feel like doing this in viewDidLoad is incorrect, but I'm not sure where it actually belongs.

viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

balls = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
CGPoint newPos = CGPointMake(5,5);

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
[balls addObject:[[[Ball alloc] init] autorelease]];
}

[[balls objectAtIndex:1] setPosition:newPos];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 / 30.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)onTimer
{
for(int i = 0; i < [balls count]; i++) {
    Ball *b = [balls objectAtIndex:i];
    [b update];
    [(BallView *)self.view refresh:b];
    }
}


- (void)refresh:(Ball *)aBall {
ball = aBall;
[self setNeedsDisplay];
```

}

I've added my onTimer, I thought adding the delay in creating the balls would be enough to make this a nonissue.  All update does is change the velocity/direction based on the accelerometer/collisions with the edge of the screen.

Comment: The allocation of the objects looks okay to me.  You should have two objects, and a debugging session should verify this.  Maybe your drawing routine doesn't know how to display each object differently?  I think we need to see your drawing routine, or other logic.

Comment: Maybe the balls follow the same path and overlap each other?

Comment: I agree. My guess is the balls are in fact drawn exactly on top of each other, because your delay does not change the timing of whatever happens in onTimer.

Comment: Try sticking a [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2]; in the end of the onTimer for loop, will be a quick way to validate the comments above, as you will see the balls strobe.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed both balls should be displayed. Check their coordinates to see if they overlap. On another note, it appears you are leaking the balls array, as well as the ball1 and ball2 objects. You are alloc init'ing them so you have to release them at the end of viewDidLoad, or, if you are using retain properties, just autorelease them when you set them so that they get retained by the properties.

As for where the code should be located, viewDidLoad should be ok, but consider putting the balls array into the init method you call to create your ViewController, since there's probably no way your ViewController could work without that array being set up.

Comment: In the printout of their coordinates, they do overlap.  However, I have tried setting one of the balls to start in a different location as seen in my edited viewDidLoad code.  For some reason, I suspect that both balls are set to be the same ball, and are updated simultaneously, not using the initialization of the other until the original one falls off the screen.  Also, I do not have an init method for my viewController to place that array in.

Comment: Okay, now I looked again, both objects are at different positions, only the most recent one is being displayed and updating.  The other one just has a constant position, is never displayed, and is never updated.

Comment: You might want to try wrapping all the visual updates you make in a performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: call.

Comment: Where in my code would this fit in?  Sorry, I'm having a hard time figuring that out, in addition to what parameters I would pass for the selector and object.

Also, from my understanding, wouldn't this only help if the first ball was updating and displaying and not the second?  I'm beginning to think that each ball requires its own view for this to work properly.

Comment: Try just wrapping everything inside onTimer with a method, say - (void) redisplay. Then inside onTimer just call [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(redisplay) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

Comment: Hmm, nothing seems to have changed when I do that.  In the debugger console, I am still seeing the first ball as not moving nor is it being displayed on my device.

With multiple balls, it appears that only the most current is having its position updated and displayed.

Comment: So I've figured out that something goes wrong between my onTimer/refresh.  setNeedsDisplay is only called for the last ball created, so drawRect never gets called for any of the previous balls.